# Problems with Vertex Arrays

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vertex-array, vertex-array-object

i'm trying to learn how to handle VBOs (VertexBufferObjects), but i can't get further than the Vertex Arrays. I followed some basic tutorials on this topic, each teaching a different way, making it hard for me to understand and implement.

Problem: Rendering with `glDrawArrays();` should work the same as rendering in immediate Mode. So i tried to test the code by [songho.ca](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html) but all i'm getting is a JVM crash inside the native code. Asking Google didn't help at all, because of dozens of variants of this Method. But i assume that my Parameters are the main problem.

Here is what i got so far:

I work with LWJGL, so i'm storing the Data in a FloatBuffer:

```
FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(triangles.size() * 3 * 3);

for(Triangle tri : triangles) {
    buffer.put((float) tri.getA().x);
    buffer.put((float) tri.getA().y);
    buffer.put((float) tri.getA().z);

    buffer.put((float) tri.getB().x);
    buffer.put((float) tri.getB().y);
    buffer.put((float) tri.getB().z);

    buffer.put((float) tri.getC().x);
    buffer.put((float) tri.getC().y);
    buffer.put((float) tri.getC().z);
}
```

My Triangle class consists of 3 Vectors A B C, each defining one Vertex. In the first line i'm allocating space for the vertices, 9 floats per Triangle (3 floats per Vertex, 3 Vertex per Triangle). So far nothing unusual, the amount of floats put inside the buffer equals exactly the allocated size.

Rendering in immediate Mode:

```
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (Triangle tri : this.triangles) {
        glVertex3d(tri.getA().x, tri.getA().y, tri.getA().z);
        glVertex3d(tri.getB().x, tri.getB().y, tri.getB().z);
        glVertex3d(tri.getC().x, tri.getC().y, tri.getC().z);
    }
    glEnd();
```

Nothing special too, everything seen so far, works fine for me. But the Array variant gives me headaches...

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, 0, buffer);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, buffer.capacity());

    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

The errorlog produced by the crashing JVM points to the `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, buffer.capacity());` line, but i can't find my mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `buffer.flip ()` to your code for one thing.

Buffers in Java have an internal current position, which is what LWJGL uses to mark the beginning of your data when you call `glVertexPointer (...)`. Each time you call `buffer.put (...)`, it increases the size of your buffer and also sets the current position to the ***end*** of the buffer.

Calling `flip (...)` will move the current position to the the ***beginning*** of the buffer. This way you will not overrun your buffer when you try to draw `capacity (...)`-many vertices starting at the "current" position.

Additionally, each vertex is built from **3** floats. The capacity here is measured in terms of the number of floating-point components, so the number of vertices stored in your buffer is actually its capacity divided by **3**.

Comment: Seems to work, i'll just do a few more tests with it.
Thanks!